# TCPDF UTF8 - weird spacing between characters

Tags: php, utf-8, tcpdf

Pls have a look at the following picture http://dev.mosaicware.pl/tmp/PDF-utf-problem.png

As you can se PL and RO characters are looking weird, they look fine on the webpage. Any clue?
I've used arialunicid0 font and following code (characters in DB are UTF-8):

```
$pdf = new models_PdfUtf(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', true); 
$pdf->SetFont('arialunicid0'); $pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, PDF_HEADER_TITLE, PDF_HEADER_STRING); 
$pdf->SetAuthor($problem . ' ' . $problem['user_surname']); $pdf->SetTitle($problem['problem_title']); 
$pdf->SetSubject($problem['problem_title']); 
$pdf->Output('export.pdf','I');
$pdf = new models_PdfUtf(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', true);
    $pdf->SetFont('arialunicid0');
    $pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, PDF_HEADER_TITLE, PDF_HEADER_STRING);
    $pdf->setPrintFooter(false);
    $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->writeHTML($c, true, 0, true, 0);
    $pdf->SetAuthor($problem . ' ' . $problem['user_surname']); 
    $pdf->SetTitle($problem['problem_title']); 
    $pdf->SetSubject($problem['problem_title']); 
    $pdf->Output('export.pdf','I');
```

Comment: Is Paragraph alignment set to Justify ?or something same as Justify ?

Comment: No. As you can see DE and CH chars are OK.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the picture is now password protected, but from your description I'd guess that there is something in the HTML. I encountered a behavior as described by cou with links. Could you check if $c contains any links at all?